# Get a specific string from a url

Tags: java

How to get the ip address/address from the url string using substring in java.

```
http://abc.com:8080/abc/abc?abc=abc
```

I want to show the output abc.com from the above url. how can I extract this from the url.

Below is my code, I have retrieved, but is it a good way?

```
String a = servlet.substring(servlet.indexOf(":")+1);
String b = a.substring(2,a.indexOf(":"));
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
String c = servlet.replace(b, "192.168.0.1");
System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: try it yourself using substring, indexOf(str) methods in combination

Comment: @Marco, sorry for late posting. I have posted the code, that what i have done.

Answer (score 6):

Use `URL` class:

```
URL url = new URL("http://abc.com:8080/abc/abc?abc=abc");
System.out.println(url.getHost());
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not use the existing [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class and call `getHost()` ?

> Gets the host name of this URL, if applicable. The format of the host
>   conforms to RFC 2732, i.e. for a literal IPv6 address, this method
>   will return the IPv6 address enclosed in square brackets ('[' and
>   ']').

Note the other useful methods on this (`getPort()` etc.). It's worth using these existing utility classes rather than roll your own solution. It looks a simple solution but the existing utilities will cater for all the edge cases.